# Can I create an int array from String arguments using 'for each' loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I wrote the following code which gave a compile time error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int number : args) {
        number = Integer.parseInt(args);
        System.out.println(number);
        int sum = 0;
        sum += number;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language

Comment: @ Nishant: Incompatible type in for loop. thats y u r getting compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. In the `for-each` statement, you must use a single variable (`String`) of array (`String[]`) to be input from array one by one. However your code uses `int` for `String[]`. **Types mismatch**.
2. The variable `sum` should be declaired outside of the loop. Unless `sum` is newly created for every loop. **Scope is inappropriate**.

Then the code would be modified like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (String arg : args) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(arg);
        System.out.println(number);
        sum += number;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second point is [incorrect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-int-). `println` can handle a variety of data types.

Comment: @resueman Thank you for your suggestion. You are right. I mistook `println` with `Log(String, String)` in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String numberText : args) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberText);
        System.out.println(numberText);
        int sum = 0;
        sum += number;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to convert that value from int to its object type reference, unless you are using string ,just remove

```
int number=Integer.parseInt(args);
```

and one thing you must pass **array** to **for each** loop .you can try like this example :

hope this will help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int[] arg = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        for (int value : arg) {
            sum += value;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```